# how to test saga yield watcher parallel calls in jest

Tags: jestjs, redux-saga, saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I want to test my saga i'm able to test individual saga calls but how can i test my watcher saga using jest

```
export default function* saga() {
  yield [
    takeLatest(dataTypeActions.ACTION1, fetchDataType),
    takeLatest(sourceActions.ACTION2, fetchFromSource),
    takeLatest(targetActions.ACTION3, fetchFromTarget),
  ];
}
```

some body will help me out how to test parallel calls using jest(uisng generator function)

Comment: @Osmel Mora can you help me this

Comment: I'd wrap the array in `all` effect and then test that the all effect is yielded. Other than that, testing that the tasks indeed run in parallel  is actually testing the redux-saga lib functionality which is imo something you shouldn't need to do.

Comment: You could check in your test that all the effects in the array are of type `fork` (which is what takeLatest returns) to make sure no one puts any other effect there.

Comment: @MartinKadlec could you please provide any example

Comment: Perhaps something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/jz68pj2z4w @kumar

Comment: @MartinKadlec thanks for example its helped me to solve the test partially,if i have more than 3yields in all call taking long time to execute

Comment: @MartinKadlec You could check in your test that all the effects in the array are of type Good Idea to test All :) cheers thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can test it like this:

```
it('watches several actions...', () => {
  const generator = yourSaga();
  expect(generator.next().value).toEqual([
    takeLatest(dataTypeActions.ACTION1, fetchDataType),
    takeLatest(sourceActions.ACTION2, fetchFromSource),
    takeLatest(targetActions.ACTION3, fetchFromTarget),
  ]);
});
```

Comment: taking such a long time to execute test greater than 15mins